# Can't use/format SD card formatted as internal storage

Tags: android, sd-card

I have a **SanDisk Ultra 16 GB SD Card** and formatted it as internal storage in my **Nokia 2.1** (Android 9 - Not rooted).

I can't use or format the sd card on my phone.

- When I choose to format it as internal storage, I get the following toast:

  `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.storage.VolumeInfo.getId()' on a null object reference.`
- When I choose the other option - formatting as removable media - the format process finished but nothing happens and my SD card is still unknown to my phone.

So I decided to format it with my computer. This is what gparted shows:
[image: gparted]

When I delete these two partitions, the operation completes, but I still have those partitons!

[image]

When I try to delete those partitions and create a new FAT32 partition using GParted, I get the following error:

```
create empty partition  00:00:04    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sdb3 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 31115263
size: 31113216 (14.84 GiB)
libparted messages    ( INFO )

Can't have overlapping partitions.
Partition(s) 3 on /dev/sdb have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use. As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use. You should reboot now before making further changes.
```

So I tried writing zero to the entire disc, using dd:

```
[dsm@dsm-pc ~]$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb status=progress
[sudo] password for dsm: 
15928488448 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 3894 s, 4.1 MB/s 
dd: writing to '/dev/sdb': No space left on device
31116289+0 records in
31116288+0 records out
15931539456 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 3922.32 s, 4.1 MB/s
```

Nothing happened after that, I still have those partitions!

I don't need my data, is there a way to format this SD Card? I checked many similar questions here and in other websites, but none of them helped.

**Update #2:**

I tried what @2419 suggested:

```
[dsm@dsm-pc ~]$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.35.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 

Partition 2 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

After that, I checked the partitions and nothing is changed!

```
[dsm@dsm-pc ~]$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.86 GiB, 15931539456 bytes, 31116288 sectors
Disk model: Storage Device  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1D5C6913-E83B-4D16-9CEC-0946D0203D84

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048    34815    32768   16M unknown
/dev/sdb2  34816 31116254 31081439 14.8G unknown
```

Comment: It looks like your card is failing. There is a state called 'gridlocked' that behaves like that, 'pretends' to be writable, but is actually read-only. You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If its a classic SD card: [Make sure the mechanical *write lock* is not endaged.](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1102/~/sd%2Fsdhc%2Fsdxc-memory-card-is-write-protected-or-locked)

Than [try fdisk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fdisk)
Find your partition with

```bsh
# fdisk -l
```

Open all partitions on the device with

```bsh
# fdisk /dev/sdb
```

Delete the last partition on the device (`/dev/sdb2`) by `d`+`Enter`. Note: fdisk selects the last partition by default.
Now one partition is left on the device. Repeat `d`+`Enter` and `/dev/sdb1` will be deleated.
**Make sure you did not format or delete anything you did not want to.** Than write all changes with `w`+`Enter`.
You could also format make a partition and format it into a layout you want to use before you write everything. Check the partition types available with `l` + `Enter`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried fdisk, but nothing happened. I edited the original post and added the outputs. See **Update #2**